# China Post EMS API / CSV download

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a courier tracking application for a client. It's the second I've done, so far having worked with UPS, TNT, AAE and BPost. All have APIs or CSV downloads which can be used.

I'm working in Codeigniter.

I just wondered if anyone has experience of automating tracking with [China Post EMS service](http://www.ems.com.cn/english.html)? The only way to get tracking data it seems is by entering a tracking code / captcha either singly or in batches of 10. Not very practical for my client who deals with 500-1000 consignments per month.

I've searched for about 4 hours this morning on how to do this, I tried calling China Post (but don't speak Chinese so didn't get anywhere with that), have emailed (no reply yet) also.

Now my client is talking about abandoning the project if we can't get this to work - problem is unless I can find a method of retrieving data, I don't see how this can be achieved.

If you have come across this issue before (and looking at Google I can see I'm not the only developer who has come across this problem) please let me know your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I've been looking for a solution to the same issue, now, what I found as a potential solution is this:

- I found a [Python GUI script](https://github.com/gotlium/track-china-post-air-mail) that uses *track-chinapost.com* and a *captcha breaker* in order to get the tracking information
- Another potential solution is using the [AfterShip](http://www.aftership.com) API which supports china post among many other couriers, but it is pretty expensive and I don't think it suits your context...

If you have found other solutions, please let me know...